Get application permissions from graph rest api
I have a application registered to allow (or not) do CRUD actions in Users. I would like to know if the aplication has those permissions in azure.
I have tried using several endpoints (application, serviceprincipal, etc) and I get information but i don't get the API permissions.
I would like to see if my application has the permission User.ReadWrite.All.

How can I get it? what rest endpoint i should use it? to get it, does it require any additional permission?
Thanks a lot in advance.
I tried using several endpoints:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq 'XXXXX'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/XXXXX
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/XXXXX/requiredResourceAccess
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/XXXXX/appRoleAssignments

and never I get that information.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted API permissions as below:

Initially, get the Object ID of this service principal that can be found in Enterprise Applications with same name:

Now, you can run below Graph API call that retrieves Application permissions with appRoleId in response like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/spObjID/appRoleAssignments

Response:

To know the name of these Application permissions, you need to use different API call that fetches MS Graph service principal with appRoles data:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')?$select=appRoles

Response:

Alternatively, you can run below Microsoft Graph PowerShell script that gives Application permissions names in response like this:
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "Application.Read.All"

$spObjId = "spObjectId"
$servicePrincipal = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'" -Property "appRoles"
$appRoleAssignments = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $spObjId
$permissions = @()

# Map AppRoleId to permission names
foreach ($assignment in $appRoleAssignments) {
    $appRoleId = $assignment.AppRoleId
    $matchedAppRole = $servicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $appRoleId }
    if ($matchedAppRole) {
        $permissions += $matchedAppRole.Value
    }
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "`nMS Graph permissions of 'Application' type granted to application are :"
foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "- $permission"
}

Response:

Reference:
List appRoleAssignments granted to a service principal - Microsoft Graph 

Hello @Sridevi, with your answer i have got it. Thank you very much!

@pereceptron Please click on checkmark beside the answer if it helped you in any way
